# 401 Unauthorized while accessing localhost/phpmyadmin in ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

I am new to Ubuntu. I am facing this issue while accessing the localhost/phpmyadmin

> 401 Unauthorized

Also, I cannot login using the username and password I set for phpmyadmin.

I have followed the tutorial from here - [Digital Ocean Tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-14-04)

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Any hint in the webserver error log? Please check the file permissions of the phpMyAdmin directory on disk so that the webserver has read permissions (and execute, for the directories).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by uninstalling the phpmyadmin and again installing the phpmyadmin.

Comment: How can I reinstall phpmyadmin? Some more words would help, welcome to so.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve it by editing:`nano /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf`

And commenting the text:

```
#       <IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
#               AuthType Basic
#               AuthName "phpMyAdmin Access"
#               AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/htpasswd
#       </IfModule>
#       Require valid-user
```

Answer (score 0):

you also  need to make changes in  /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess file

type `vim  /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess and edit file`

and comment the lines

```
 # AuthType Basic
 # Authname "Restricted files"
 # AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
 # Require valid-user
```

This will resolve the problem of asking password to access directory.